# Compiler complains '/226 error in C' referring to a minus in code

Tags: c

Please see the following code. Based on previous strings it appears the /226 error is that the compiler interprets the "-" sign as 226 in octal and does not accept it in C code.

Please note that the code as posted might not exhibit the described behavior, because the "minus" in question might not make it in its special representation to your compiler (editors and browsers being in the way....).
This is as close to an MCVE as it is possible to be.

So how do I get it to just be interpreted as a "-" sign?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int auxiliary;

    int arr[5];
    printf("Enter your5 digit array: ");
    scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &arr);

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        auxiliary = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[5 – x];
        arr[5 – x] = auxiliary;
    }

    printf("the sorted array is: %d,", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[5 – x]` is out of bounds when `x==0`

Comment: You have UB on your code. `arr[5-x]` when `x=0`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Same time. I wonder why your comment got on top? they sort by rep? :)

Comment: nope, hover over the "57 secs ago", you'll see the exact time. Beat you by 1 second.

Comment: (and yes I beat you because of my higher rep :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Ow...I see..1 sec it is. haha :D

Comment: This is new to me  `scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &arr);`.... did I miss something?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, it's C40 (standard from 2040). Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't understand it yet and interprets that as UB

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A yes, I have the concept white paper here. It is mentioned just after the "dwim()" function extension in <readmind.h>.

Comment: `226` may be the byte value of some "smart hyphen" because `-` is ASCII 45. Suggest you do not use Microsoft Word or so for editing programs.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling an answer from comments, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions:

a)

```
int main(int argc)
```

This is none of the accepted function heads for `main`.

b)

There is incorrectness in your way of using `scanf` for array. (This insufficiency of arguments is undefined behavior).

```
scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &arr);
```

c)

```
arr[x] = arr[5 – x];
```

Is an access beyond your array in case of `x` is equal to `0` and hence undefined behaviour.

d)

```
printf("the sorted array is: %d,", arr);
```

The misuse of `printf` for array here is kind of consistent with above.

e) 
Most importantly for you, because it most plausibly explains what you are actually asking about (credits to Paul Olgivie).

`226` may be the byte value of some "smart hyphen" because `-` is ASCII 45. Suggest you do not use Microsoft Word or so for editing programs.
Using the alternate/correct version of the "minus", might solve your problem.

Comment: Mention about the printing `arr` with `%d` format specifier.

Comment: Thank you, but even if the for loop is changed so x starts at 1 the same error occurs. How would you FIX this?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
 
 int main(int argc,char *argv[] )
 {
  int x;
  int y;
  int auxiliary;
  
  
  int arr [5]= {9,6,4,3,1} ;
  printf("Enter your5 digit array: \n\n");
  scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d",&arr);
  
  
  
  
  for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
   {
     auxiliary = arr[x];
     arr[x] = arr[5 – x];
     arr[5 – x] = auxiliary;
  } 

 printf("The sorted array is: %d,", arr);
 return 0;
  
 }

Comment: @NoelNosse, you can't print an array with `%d`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I consider your input to be most likely the actual answer. If you make one and ask me too, I will remove your input here.